# Is is possible to apply custom encryption to Microsoft Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

We are using Web API 2.0 to serve clients in a context where SSL can't be used (no public internet access, clients can't be expected to trust a self-signed certificate). To secure content moving between the client and server, we'd like to be able to encrypt it. We're OK with un-encrypted HTTP headers (only need to encrypt payload). The question is: is there a way to insert a custom handler into both the request and response message pipelines so that we can apply a decryption as a request pre-processing step and an encryption as a response post-processing step?

We are using the built-in features of Web API to serialize/de-serialize between JSON and model classes, and don't want to have to refactor any of that existing code. So an encryption handler would have to be inserted at the very start/end of the request/response pipeline. Is this possible, and if so, what is the technique to insert custom request/response content pre/post processing?

The network is "public" in that users bring their own devices, but the network is isolated from the public internet. Clients will only use a custom application we are developing to consume our Web API service, so we can address implementation issues of a custom encryption scheme on both client and server side.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you can't use SSL. This is a corporate network? You can have clients trust an enterprise Certificate Authority, and have your CA sign the certificates. Then when clients access your site they'll see the cert and that it was signed by a CA that they trust, and they'll be happy.

Comment: Do you have a plan for how clients will be able to decrypt and encrypt payloads on their side?  I'd expect if you are in control of the client enough for them to do this, then you should be able to establish a certificate trust relationship.

Comment: If you really must, use a custom media formatter, but I'd opt for SSL though.

Comment: As I understand it, the clients will need to decrypt within the browser, which means your decryption algorithm will need to be sent as a piece of unencrypted JavaScript, which will negate the security provided by the server.

Comment: @Alan good encryption/decryption algorithms are public anyway (and have JavaScript implementations)... But keys are way more interesting :)

Comment: Yep, I should have said keys, not algorithm... if the OP can't simply add a custom CA to the client's store, I assume there's no way they can ship anything outside of normal HTTP traffic.

Comment: @mason just edited my post to hopefully clarify the issues with CAs and trust.

Comment: @CarlR. That makes more sense. But still, the way I've seen this done in the past is to provide directions for how to add the trust for the company's CA. You could even automate this process by telling users to run a script located somewhere on the network. It's either this, or figure out some way of getting the decryption key to the client. One is straightforward (using SSL with your own CA) and the other isn't (figuring out how to set up the encryption decryption layers, figuring out how to perform the key exchange).

Answer (score 0):

If you control the client application, you can hard-code the SSL certificate that the server is expected to return, which means that it doesn't have to validate through the normal PKI means (sometimes called [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning)).  Most other approach will result in you attempting to re-invent SSL, but with some fatal flaw.

To be explicit, I think you are seeing a conflict between "a context where SSL can't be used (no public internet access, clients can't be expected to trust a self-signed certificate)" and "Clients will only use a custom application we are developing" where one doesn't necessarily exist.  The user doesn't have to know that the certificate is self-signed, and self-signed does not always imply untrusted.